# Using Lambda Expressions for RoutedEventHandler

Tags: wpf

I'm installing an event handler successfully with this code:

```
this.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(tabLabel_MouseLeftButtonDown), true); ...
void tabLabel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsSelected = true;
 }
```

Now I tried to make the code more compact using a Lambda expression like this:

```
this.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, (s, e) => { this.IsSelected = true; }, true);
```

It gives me the error message:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type.

I cannot figure out how it should be done. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   this.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((sender,e) => this.IsSelected=true), true);
```

The problem arises because the compiler knows that the second argument to AddHandler is of type System.Delegate, which is abstract. Without a concrete type, it can't infer the types of the parameters in the lambda.

We don't have to use RoutedEventHandler here, we can create something with the same signature: `Action<object,EventArgs>` which also works, but the version above is shorter.

```
    this.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,  new Action<object,EventArgs>((sender, e) => IsSelected = true), true);
```

Comment: The OP was trying to make the code more compact using a lambda expression.

Comment: @arbitrary while this does answer the question, it might be helpful if you explained to the OP why yours works and his doesn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The explanation helps, I now know what i need to study a bit more carefully (the delegate stuff).